# Is there a way to merge a grid with a shapefile?

Tags: qgis-3, spatial-join, vector-grid

I'm using QGIS and I have a shapefile that's a grid I created and another shapefile that is points.  I would like to join them so each grid section is linked with points that fall within in.  The grid geolocations are "left/top/right/bottom."  The shapefile has latitude and longitude.  Is there a way to join the two files if there is no common field?  Can you convert the grid's coordinates to latitude and longitude and then join them?  [image]

[image]

Comment: So how exactely you want to join them? If there are several points: how should they be linked and what sould be linked?

Comment: I wanted to create a shapefile where each point corresponds with the grid square it's located in. But maybe that's not possible.  Does the grid only reference the four corner points of each cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Menu Vector / Data Management Tools /Join attributes by location`. In the screenshot below, I used a polygon grid as input (base layer) and joined it to the points (Join layer). Check the `intersects` box.

As you can see, you get a new polygon layer with both the id of the polygon (first row) and the id of the points inside this polygon (or `NULL` if there are no points, as in cell no. 1).

[image]

Of course, you can run the tool also the other way round: joining the points to the polygons (insted of polygons to points) and you get a new point layer containing the id of the polygon each points lies in. Thus simply switch the input layers as can be seen here:

[image]

Thus, you don't need the grid's coordinates, even though there would be some ways to create what you want using coordinates - but that would be more complicated. You could also use QGIS expressions (e.g. `overlay_intersects` or `overlaps`), but again, thut would basically do the same thing as `Join attributes by location` in a more complicated way.